# Nginx fastcgi_read_timeout at specific location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I would like to increase the fastcgi_read_timeout at location level for nginx. However it doesn't work. The fastcgi_read_timeout is still 6 instead of 10. My config file is :

```
server {

listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
index index.php;

root /websites/somesite.org;
server_name somesite.org;
fastcgi_read_timeout 6s;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    internal;
}

# increase timeout for charity uploads
location = /charities/charities/import/ {
    fastcgi_read_timeout 10s;
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# any other php extension should fail
location ~ \.php$ {
    return 403;
}
```

}

However if I add return 403; in place of fastcgi_read_timeout 10s; it correctly returns 403. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

It does not work because the `fastcgi_read_timeout` directive must either be in the same `location` as the `fastcgi_pass` or at the `server` level.

Hence you should either set it for the whole `server` block or add the `fastcgi_pass` directive to the `location` with the specific timeout.

In your case that would look something like:

```
# increase timeout for charity uploads
location = /charities/charities/import/ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 10s;
    fastcgi_pass worker:9000;
}
```

Of course that depends on the way your PHP script works, maybe you'll need to hard set PHP-FPM's `SCRIPT_FILENAME` (with `fastcgi_param`).

Comment: I may not understand fully what you mean. I have added fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; to the same location and problem remains. Would you modify my posted config in a way it works ? Thank you !